# What does this icon in my notification window mean?

Tags: sony-xperia

Recently an icon has started to appear in my notification window. What does it mean ?

[image: screenshot]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its shows that your phone is in **Extended Standby Mode**.

You can find it in `Settings->PowerManagemnet`

Extended standby mode increases the standby time by reducing the background activities when the phone is in standby mode.

Data will automatically be turned off and background activities will be stopped from waking up , while applications will also be prevented from syncing data.

You will still be able to receive calls and texts, while the calendar application and  alarms will still feature normally. As soon as you unlock your smartphone it'll go returning to functioning normally.

Any ongoing downloads or bluetooth transfer will be allowed to complete and once completed data will be turned off.

**Extended standby mode** is replaced with **Stamina Mode** for Xperia running on Jellybean or higher

Source : [SONY](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2012/10/05/learn-about-extended-standby-mode-sonys-new-power-save-feature-video/)

Answer (score 0):

This iS Battery STAMINA Mode.

With Sony’s power management
setting called Battery STAMINA
Mode, you can extend the standby
time of your Xperia™ device by more
than four times. With Battery
STAMINA Mode turned on, the
background activities of most
applications are reduced when you
turn off the screen.